# activity and fragment layouts in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

just a quick question because I feel a bit confused by this:

I have both `fragment_main.xml` AND `activity_main.xml` created by android studio.
By using the Graphical layout, I can drag and drop buttons and what not in both fragment and activity. 
The difference is, fragment lets me move stuff around freely, while activity_main doesn't.

```
Why is that? Is activity_main locked or something?
```

Also, should I leave the `activity_main.xml` blank and just work on fragments?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the edit, Hermant Chand Dungriyal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no difference between fragment and activity layout they inflate whatever layout xml file which you are created. according to your explanation i think your activity layout contain linear layout so you view can be organize in vertical or horizontal form. use instead of relative layout in which you can  the positions of the children in relation to each other or to the parent.  [for more info click this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts)

Comment: So basically I can use fragment_main.xml and do everything in there. The activity_main.xml only lets me select pre-determined positions based on horizontal or vertical lines, so it might be in Linear Layout mode. thank you for your answer and the link.

Comment: While this answers the first part of the question, it doesn't explain the second (and more important) question: leave activity layout blank and just work on fragment? The answer is related to [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) and [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: Your answer was helpful mcd, but just as Andrew T said, it doesn't fully resolve all my questions. Should I leave activity layout blank and just work on fragment_main.xml?

Comment: there is not mandatory to add layout in activity . you can comment out or remove setContetntView method there is not mandatory to add view in activity

Comment: Thank you! I accepted the answer. now I understand it well, thanks to your help. Upvote my question if you think it was good, so others can see it. I'm sure there's people who run into this confusion and they would like to know.